# Imprimir el numero de versión de publicación

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

acabe mi aplicación en visual studio C# ahora la voy a publicar en el servidor,
tengo este formulario donde muestra el Abuot osea "Acerca de" 
y tengo esta versión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo yo  imprimir este versión en mi formulario y que esta cuando yo haga una actualización o suba la versión, la suba automáticamente en el formulario 
es decir que me imprima la versión que ponga sin tener que poner nada manual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que esta en rojo es un label necesito que ese label se actualice cada vez que publique o actualice mi app

Answer (score 2):

Si el desarrollo es `Windows Application` podrias usar

[Application.ProductVersion](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.productversion?view=netframework-4.5)

entonces seria

```
lblVersion.Text = string.Format("Version: {0}", Application.ProductVersion);
```

---

Aunque siempre esta la posibilidad de hacer por el `assembly`

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

pero para esto recuerda agregar el using a `System.Reflection`

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente debes acceder a [Application.ProductVersion](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.productversion?view=netframework-4.8)

```
string version = Application.ProductVersion;
```

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que estás utiizando ClickOnce para hacer tu deploy. La versión no la vas a poder ver cuando estás haciendo debug (corriendo tu programa desde visual studio) por eso debes comprobar primero el deploy. Aquí te dejo el código que yo uso en mis aplicaciones:

```
 if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
        string strVersion = "Versión: " +   ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString();
```

Espero te sea de utilidad